# Google Cloud Compute - MetaData is not set for VM-Instance

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform

My code is setting the following MetaData for the instance. The Request is processed properly but the MetaData is not showing up in the Cloud Console. I tried a number of variations to set the MetaData.
Is there a way to see the requests I made to the API in the Google Cloud Console?
Do you have any suggestions on setting the metadata object better or even functional?

```
        Instance instance = new Instance();
    log.debug(gsi.getInstanceId()+" is being created");
    instance.setName(gsi.getInstanceId());
    instance.setMachineType(MACHINE_TYPE);
    Metadata metaData = new Metadata();
    metaData = metaData.set("gslt",gsi.getGameServerLoginToken());
    metaData = metaData.set("rcon",gsi.getRcon());
    instance.setMetadata(metaData);
    try {
        Compute.Instances.Insert insert = compute
                .instances()
                .insert(PROJECT_ID,REGION,instance)
                .setSourceInstanceTemplate(INSTANCE_TEMPLATE)
                .setZone(REGION)
                .setProject(PROJECT_ID);
        Operation op = insert.execute();

        var context = this;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                blockUntilComplete(compute,op,300*1000);
                instanceEventPublisher.publishInstanceCreatedEvent(context, instance.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

I will send additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job just well and is presumably a better solution.

```
    Metadata metaData = new Metadata();
    Metadata.Items gslt = new Metadata.Items();
    gslt.setKey("gslt");
    gslt.setValue(gsi.getGameServerLoginToken().getToken());
    Metadata.Items rcon = new Metadata.Items();
    rcon.setKey("rcon");
    rcon.setValue(gsi.getRcon());
    metaData.setItems(new ArrayList<>());
    metaData.getItems().add(gslt);
    metaData.getItems().add(rcon);
    instance.setMetadata(metaData);
```

Found two examples under [programmcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php%3Fsource_dir=AndroidAppDeployer-master/AndroidAppDeployer/src/com/appjma/appdeployer/receiver/?class=com.google.api.services.compute.model.Metadata&method=setItems)